# Grouping results and combining duplicates as array

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a query that gets all the records grouped by `code` and the rows that are duplicated are aggregated into an array.

```
+----------+---------+
| code     | name    |
+----------+---------+
| a        | Mike    |
| b        | Jones   |
| b        | Who     |
+----------+---------+
```

expected result:

```
+----------+----------------+
| code     | name           |
+----------+----------------+
| a        | Mike           |
| b        | [Jones, Who]   |
+----------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe SQLServer 2017 introduced `STRING_AGG`:

```
select code, string_agg(name, '') as data
from T
group by code
```

Comment: That looks awesome, but the command wasn't found. I searched around and found out this db is using SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good exemple on how you can achieve it:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FamilyMemberPets
(
  Name SYSNAME,
  Pet SYSNAME,
  PRIMARY KEY(Name,Pet)
);
 
INSERT dbo.FamilyMemberPets(Name,Pet) VALUES
(N'Madeline',N'Kirby'),
(N'Madeline',N'Quigley'),
(N'Henry',   N'Piglet'),
(N'Lisa',    N'Snowball'),
(N'Lisa',    N'Snowball II');


SELECT Name, Pets = STUFF((SELECT N', ' + Pet 
  FROM dbo.FamilyMemberPets AS p2
   WHERE p2.name = p.name 
   ORDER BY Pet
   FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 2, N'')
FROM dbo.FamilyMemberPets AS p
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name;

drop table FamilyMemberPets
```